# Flutter App - Google Play payment taking priority over Amazon Payment flow - RevenueCat

Tags: android, flutter, revenuecat

I have a query about Amazon and subscriptions/IAP payments within our app.

We have implemented our app using RevenueCat for billing, for Google Android, Apple iOS, and now for Amazon Android.

We are testing our Amazon implementation (Amazon Live App Testing), and when we tap to pay for an in-app purchase or a subscription on a non-amazon device (i.e. regular Android Device (13)), it triggers the Google Play payment flow, instead of the Amazon Payment Flow.

To make purchases in Google Play, we need to use the Google BillingClient library.
To make purchases in the Amazon store, we need to use the Amazon SDK.
This is all via RevenueCat.

These SDKs are bundled in our app when we build it. Since Google Play is installed on a regular device(not an Amazon device), Google Play payment seems to be taking priority over the Amazon payment flow.

Has anyone else come across this scenario, would appreciate any input.